# Wrong charset output when using var_dump()

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, opencart2.x

I'm using Opencart 2.1.0.2

When I'm debugging with `var_dump()` I have output with the wrong charset. But if I use `die` after that I have a nice output.

This's the bad one:

[image: var_dump() output]

At the very top of `index.php` I put `echo mb_internal_encoding(); die;` and I got `ISO-8859-1`. So then I put `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8')` before that. But it didn't help.

Also, I recursively checked all files on charset with `mb_detect_encoding($file)`. All files have `UTF-8` or `ASCII` charset.

`php.ini` has `default_charset = UTF-8`

I'm using [hosting Ukraine](https://www.ukraine.com.ua/). I set `UTF-8` as a default charset.

But none of these things helped.

Do you guys have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. This line in `index.php` causes the bad output. I have no idea why. So I just commented it out.

```
$response->setCompression($config->get('config_compression'));
```